# How to prevent tags separating text in word xml file?

Tags: php, xml, ms-word

I am recently working on read word xml file using my php program. For example, in the word xml file the text is [hx_ocdstart], but if you look inside the code of this xml file it looks like:

```
[</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts 
w:ascii="Calibri" w:h-ansi="Calibri"/><wx:font wx:val="Calibri"/><w:color w:val="660066"/></w:rPr><w:t>hx_puberty_</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:h-ansi="Calibri"/>
<wx:font wx:val="Calibri"/><w:color w:val="660066"/></w:rPr>
<w:t>ocdstart</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="22"/><w:sz-cs w:val="22"/></w:rPr><w:t>]
```

This simple text is separated by those xml tags so I cannot find the [hx_ocdstart] variable. Is there any method which can let word xml file not separate the text?

Comment: You can see this part of text are totally separated by those tags

Comment: Here are actually two ways. One is to validate that the respective ancestor tag contains the specified text content, another to check for both tags. They would use `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. Unfortunately you did not provide an valid XML and/or your current source, so I can not implement an example.